# STL array from C array without copying

Tags: c++

Is there a way to encapsulate a C-array with a fixed size in an STL container?
In other words, let's say I have a C-array `arrC` with size `size`, I want a container (that does not involve copying) that uses `arrC` but implements the usual functions and iterators. This is the use case I am thinking about:

```
int arrC[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
auto myarr = c_array(arrC, 6);   // The data is not saved internally here, just the pointer and the size
for (auto itr=myarr.begin();itr!=myarr.end();++itr)
     std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
```

Of course, I understand that this might be unsafe since I can free arrC.

EDIT: The reason I need this is because my C++ provides a C-interface to other languages (including Python) and I want to be able to process the data that is passed to my C++ functions without having to copy it.

Comment: I believe the closest you can get is to use std::array instead of a C array.

Comment: STL containers manage their own memory, so, no, this isn't possible.

Comment: you know that you can loop from `begin` to `end` through a c array without having to get the data into a std container ?

Comment: I wonder if a reinterpret cast can portably get you an `array<T,N>` reference to an array `T[N]`?

Comment: C is a different language. Don't spam tags.

Comment: I have to write a C-interface for another language and I want to be able to use my C++ code to access the data that is passed to me without having to copy it (I added an explanation in the question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but implements the usual functions ...

You mean like the array overloads of [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), which enable new-style `for` loops to work automatically?

> ...and iterators

And the fact that raw pointers are automatically RandomAccessIterators, because that's how iterators were designed?

---

That is, the modern idioms

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
// demonstrate that the overloads exist ...
auto b = std::begin(a);
auto e = std::end(a);
// and that b,e work correctly as InputIterators ...
std::cout << "distance=" << (std::distance(b, e)) << '\n';
std::cout << "elements=" << (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) << '\n';
// and further that they're explicitly described as RandomAccessIterators ...
std::cout << "random access="
    << std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<decltype(b)>::iterator_category,
                    std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value << '\n';
// and finally that new-style for just works ...
std::cout << "{";
for (auto i : a) {
    std::cout << i << ',';
}
std::cout << "}\n";
```

will give the expected output:

```
distance=6
elements=6
random access=1
{1,2,3,4,5,6,}
```

You're out of luck if you wanted to write

```
for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
```

instead, but why would you?

Comment: yeah, this is part of the reason for preferring the new (well, C++11) free functions to the old methods.

Comment: The first example doesn't use the `b` and `e` variables in the `for` loop. They can be used in the second example, though: `for (auto i = std::begin(a); i != std::end(a); ++i)`, which is essentially what `for (auto i : a)` does internally.

Comment: True, that's just a disconnected snippet showing that the functions exist.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted `a.begin()` and `a.end()`. But I guess I shouldn't have been using them in the first place to access STL containers.

Comment: Actually. This doesn't solve the issue when I need to handle an pointer of type `int*` which I know points to an array of a certain size.

Comment: True - if the array already decayed to a pointer, you need something to explicitly reintroduce information about the length - avoiding decay in the first place is probably simplest.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not anything in the standard library for that particular task (though `std::array` sort of reverses the situation: it doesn't let you wrap around an existing array, but does basically guarantee that its storage will be a simple array).

The [Guideline Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/tree/master/include/gsl) does include a `span` class for pretty much this purpose though.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has an [`array_view` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305260.aspx) for this very purpose:

> Represents an N-dimensional view over the data held in another container.